# What if @import cannot be found?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, import

I'm trying to import Bootstrap in the Ubuntu terminal using

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

and getting a return

```
No command '@import' found, did you mean:
 Command 'import' from package 'imagemagick' (main)
 Command 'import' from package 'graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat' (universe)
@import: command not found
```

The import is part of a tutorial in Ruby on Rails. Is there a command that I'm missing or a gem that I need?

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
    gem 'rspec-rails','2.11.0'
end

gem 'json'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'

  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

group :test do
    gem 'capybara','1.1.2'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Comment: You need to add @import "bootstrap" not in your terminal but in your CSS file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@import "bootstrap"` goes at the top of the CSS file you are creating for your tutorial. This will load the bootstrap CSS styles (associated with the gem: 'bootstrap-sass'). You would want to add this to your CSS page within the app/assets/stylesheets directory.

For example, check out [this stylesheet](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss) from the Rails Tutorial. You'll see the bootstrap CSS styles are referenced this way on the first line, in a file called custom.css.scss (.scss means you can use sass markup on your css page).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, the ubuntu terminal will not run ruby commands..  Your ubuntu terminal is telling you that @import is not a recognized program/alias/method/whatever else that ubuntu could recognize and return some kind of results.  @import is apparently a ruby command, though I'm not familiar with it.  With the '@' in front of it, it looks more like a global variable than a command.  Anyway, are you sure your tutorial told you to insert that code directly into the terminal? or were you supposed to put it in a pry session, or possibly a ruby script file & run `ruby scriptfile.rb` on it?  I would double-check the steps on your tutorial.  Can you give more info on what tutorial you are following?  What version of ruby, and what version of rails, as well as what version of ubuntu?